# Creating a program to calculate a formula including an exponent

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pow

I have to create a program that uses this formula in C++: A = X(1.0 + R/100)^N

However, whenever I use the pow function to properly handle the exponents, I get very different answers than I should.

```
    int main()
{
    double X, R, N;
    double sid = 1.0;
    double bid = 100;

    cout << "Input the initial deposit.\n" << endl;
    cin >> X;
    cout << "Input the amount of years.\n" << endl;
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Input the percent interest.\n" << endl;
    cin >> R; 
    cout << X * (sid + R / pow(bid, N)) << endl;


return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure where exactly I went wrong, whether it being the pow function or just how I set up the equation within the program.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it is:

```
X*pow(sid + R/bid,N);
```